# Raspberry Piのスペックでギターエフェクターは作れますか

Tags: raspberry-pi

Raspberry Piでギターエフェクターのようなものをつくりたいのですがスペック的に可能でしょうか？実際に購入してみて試したいのですがお金があまりなく実際に試してみた人や詳しい方の意見が聞きたいです。最初はArduinoでやろうと思ったのですがスペック的に高度な処理は行えないと聞いたのでRaspberry Pi2ならクロック周波数が900MHzもあるので大丈夫じゃないかなと思ったのです.

Comment: 言語などにもよりますが、PythonとPyoというライブラリを組み合わせた簡単なDSPの例がありますので参考まで: http://goo.gl/4xPhEl

Answer (score 7):

時間がたっての回答すみません。

Raspberry Pi(B+)でエフェクターを作りました。
詳細は↓です。

http://qiita.com/abtc/items/936fd13a5d9b3b4521ed

IIRのフィルターでCPUを10%位使う感じですね。メモリーはそんなに使ってないので、A+,B+で十分かな？と思っております。